# Ubuntu 14.04 became too laggy after installing fglrx-15.302

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 installed on my Toshiba Satellite L850-Y3110 Laptop alongside Windows 8.1. Recently I installed AMD Radeon Crimson 15.12 Driver (fglrx-15.302). I verified that Ubuntu detected my Graphic card by going to  Power Button -> About This Computer. As is seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmPmq.jpg), the display is not proper, and the interface is very sluggish. I have ATI Radeon HD 7670M 2GB Graphic card.

The output of `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12` is :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Radeon HD 7670M [1179:fb22]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at c0040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

What can be done to run the Graphics Driver in a usable way?